# Updating column based on another column's value

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do i update table structured like this:

```
id[pkey] | parent_id  | position
1           1           
2           1
3           1
4           1
5           1

6           2
7           2
8           2
9           2

10          3
11          3
12          3

...and so on
```

to achieve this result:

```
id[pkey] | parent_id  | position       
1           1               1
2           1               2
3           1               3
4           1               4
5           1               5

6           2               1
7           2               2
8           2               3
9           2               4

10          3               1
11          3               2
12          3               3

...and so on
```

I was thinking about somehow mixing

```
SELECT DISTINCT parent_id FROM cats AS t;
```

with

```
CREATE SEQUENCE dpos;
UPDATE cats t1 SET position = nextval('dpos') WHERE t.parent_id = t1.parent_id;
DROP SEQUENCE dpos;
```

although im not really experienced with postgres, and not sure how to use some kind of FOREACH. I appreciate any help

Comment: Do you have a primary key for that table?

Comment: @User2012384 I do, the table in fact has many columns, i just simplified my question. I updated it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the incremental number using `row_number()`.  The question is how to assign it to a particular row.  Here is one method using a `join`:

```
update cats
    set position = c2.newpos
    from (select c2.*, c2.ctid as c_ctid,
                 row_number() over (partition by c2.parent_id order by NULL) as seqnum
          from cats c2
         ) c2
    where cats.parent_id = c2.parent_id and cats.ctid = c2.c_ctid;
```

Comment: that actually worked for me(you missed a comma after c2.ctid = c_ctid though), thank you!

Comment: @springenthusiast . . . I also missed the `as` somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number function

```
select parent_id, 
row_number() over (partition by parent_id order by parent_id) as position_id from table
```

Comment: that almost did the trick, althought it only shows the wanted result. how do I update the table to those values?

Comment: I would say instead of updating the table, just create a view that has this code and use that view

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    UPDATE table_name set table_name.dataID = v_table_name.rn
FROM  
(
    SELECT row_number() over (partition by your_primaryKey order by your_primaryKey) AS rn, id
    FROM table_name
) AS v_table_name
WHERE v_table_name.your_primaryKey = v_table_name.your_primaryKey;
```